# How can I pass a parameter along with f.submit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form for creating a new user. I'd like to pass a paramater, page, with f.submit, something like:

```
<%= f.submit (:cove_id=>@cove)%>
```

Is this possible in Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the parameter inside the form, not in the submit button (for example, use a `hidden_field` to do that)

Answer (score 0):

Also, if cove_id is a foreign key on a parent model (ie: your form model belongs_to cove), consider going the nested resources route.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources